# minimize js payload with ionic framework

Tags: javascript, webview, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile web page screen for our native app. The page includes calling HTTP service, infinite scrolling and a tab view. For this purpose, I choose using ionic framework and it has came out beautifully, except that payload of the page is huge ~ around 700 KB. It is because of the ionic js and css.

Is there a way I can selectively choose the components to be included in JS and CSS so as to minimize this payload size?

What other options do I have?

Comment: In Ionic the page, js and CSS are on the mobile device, so why 700kb is so big?

Comment: If you have a native app, you can try to embed ionic.js as an asset in the app, and load it from index.html with relative path.